# An internal error occurred during: "Launching f.xml". org/eclipse/m2e/profiles/core/internal/MavenProfilesCoreActivator

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

got internal error during runnig testng tests in eclipse please help An internal error occurred during: "Launching TestNG_testng.xml". org/eclipse/m2e/profiles/core/internal/MavenProfilesCoreActivator

when i remove maven configurations its work but not in maven environment.

Comment: Are your Eclipse and the plugins you installed up to date? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Hey @howlger      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/m2e/profiles/core/internal/MavenProfilesCoreActivator

Comment: Please [add the information you been asked for to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77261426/edit). The first line of the stack trace is not enough as it does not tell by what the missing class is required. Most likely something is out of date, your Eclipse or a plugin you have installed.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/m2e/profiles/core/internal/MavenProfilesCoreActivator
 at org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getVMArgsFromPom(MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.java:96)
 at org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getVmArguments(MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.java:46)
 at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getJvmArgs(ConfigurationHelper.java:176)
 at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launchTypes(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:159)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core.internal.MavenProfilesCoreActivator cannot be found by org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)

Comment: its worked I updated the testng version from 6.11 to 6.14 thanks for the help @howlger

Comment: As I told you. `org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520` means version 6.11.0, released March 1, 2017. That's more than six years behind.

Answer (score 2):

I had updated the testng version from 6.11 to 6.14 and it fixed the problem.